# Remove Radio Buttons from Magento Checkout Login

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, login

I am trying to separate the "Create new Account" and "Checkout as Guest" options into two columns, so my checkout login will feature three separate columns: "Checkout as Guest", "Create new Account", "Login to existing Account". For this to work, I need to remove the radio buttons and add the setMethod function to the buttons. Will this require changing the function itself in `opcheckout.js`, or can this be achieved by editing the login template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this guide](http://www.creativemgroup.com/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/24-magento-remove-the-ugly-radio-buttons-from-checkout) and tried following it step by step without any luck. I then tried adding the modified setMethod function to *opcheckout_rwd.js* instead of *opcheckout.js* and it seems to be working now.

This is the code I am inserting into opcheckout_rwd.js:

```
Checkout.prototype.setMethod = function (methodtype) {
    if (methodtype=='guest') {
        this.method = 'guest';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
        );
        Element.hide('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing');
    }
    else if(methodtype=='register') {
        this.method = 'register';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
        );
        Element.show('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing');
    }
    else {
        alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest'));
        return false;
    } }
```

The edits to login.phtml can be adapted from the guide. The only concern I am having right now, is that I am not sure if this breaks support for persistent carts since I had to remove this entire part from login.phtml:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('persistent/index/saveMethod'); ?>">
                    <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="submit" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
```

to prevent having the button load the billing step with &register added to the url (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857002/magento-is-adding-register-in-the-url-of-onepage-checkout-when-you-click-reg)). I am not using persistent carts so it is not an issue for me...